# JTable, Can't retrieve data on spesific cell when cursor is still pointing inside the cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

I want to post a picture, but I don't have reputation on this site, but I described my problem below  :

```
| Name   | Grade  |
__________________
|  Febri |    60| <---- if this is a cell (row0,column1), 
                    I can't retrieve data on this cell if cursor is 
                    still pointing inside that cell.

take a look :

System.out.println(mytable.getValueAt(0,0)); --> output : Febri
System.out.println(mytable.getValueAt(0,1)); -- > output :    

that's because my mouse's cursor is still pointing inside that cell ..

Any suggestions? Is this problem related to mouse listener?

Please help , thx.
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

public class myTable extends JFrame {


String heads[] = { "Name", "Grade" };
Object[][] data = { { "Febri", "60" } };

JTable table;
JButton button;
JScrollPane scroll;

public myTable() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    table = new JTable(data, heads);


    scroll =new JScrollPane(table);

    button = new JButton("Retrieve Data");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == button) {
                System.out.println(table.getValueAt(0, 0));
                System.out.println(table.getValueAt(0, 1));
            }
        }
    });

    add(scroll);
}

public static void main(String args[])

{

    myTable tbl = new myTable();
    tbl.setVisible(true);
    tbl.setSize(500, 400);

} }
```

Comment: Post example code if possible

Comment: You mean that the cell is still editable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example works (mostly) fine.

I assume you mean while the cell is editable it won't return the value which the editor is showing?

This makes sense, as the value contained by the editor hasn't yet been committed to the model.

What you can do is stop the current editing process if the table is in edit model, this will commit the value from the editor to the model, which you can then read...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == button) {
        // Is the table in edit mode?
        if (table.isEditing()) {
            // Get the current editor
            TableCellEditor editor = table.getCellEditor();
            if (editor != null) {
                // Try and stop the cell editing process
                if (!editor.stopCellEditing()) {
                    // Cancel the editing if can't be stopped...
                    // You could handle an error state here instead...
                    editor.cancelCellEditing();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(table.getValueAt(0, 0));
        System.out.println(table.getValueAt(0, 1));
    }
}
```

Of course, this all comes down to what it is you  are trying to achieve...

Comment: Thx, for replay , yes that's because when we r still editing value on that cell, the table won't commit data on that cell. But i'm still waiting the real implementation (at least an example) for your suggestion , any site or discussion that u can refer me to go to ??

Comment: What do you mean by "real implementation"?  Either of the two answers provided we accomplish what you want - you can't get the value from the cell until it's commit to the model - that's the reality...

Comment: i mean "tutorials/examples", your answer is the correct one , but i dont know how to implement that in Java codes ? of course i can't simply write like "myTable.setEnable(false);"

Comment: You could take a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: WOW i didn't see that you already created solution for me  by using  "TableCellEditor", i thought u just repeated my code, sorry :D, And Thank u, i'll try it....

Comment: THANK U VERY MUCH  MadProgrammer , i already tested it at work, your solution WORKS LIKE A CHARM !!! u're not just helping me,but also help my 2 other team member !.. thanks again.. :)

Comment: Just note, that camickr's suggestions are also worth understanding and will produce a simular result with less code

Comment: yes Agree. but i'm little bit scared about bugs, coz this is a prototype of a software that we're working for company, my boss asked me for a simple & consistent way. :)

Comment: The bug only relates to having the `JTable` in a `JInternalFrame` under Java 6, if you know about, you can...make work arounds :P

Comment: Maybe I should buy you a beer , LOL. Yes that's exactly i'm afraid of , i'm not the one who touching the codes, i'm afraid of if they improve the table's model, and make something wrong. LOL

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop editing of the cell. [Table Stop Editing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/) shows two ways to do this. One as demonstrated by MadProgrammer and the other allows you so set a property on the JTable.

Comment: +1 to the property, just beware, that under Java 6, this won't work when the table resides within a `JInternalFrame`...welcome to 2 years of my life...hence the reason for example code :P

Comment: Apparently it has something to do with the `JInternalFrame`s automatic focus bug that was suppose to be fixed from 5-6.  It appears to be fixed in 7 though...still not getting back 2 years of my life scratching my head over it.  End up copying whole sections of the `JTable` code to wrap our own solution around it...not happy in either case :P

Comment: Thx for reply, i will search tutorials on google by using something like 'stop' editing n i'll report the result later..

Comment: It works already by using  MadProgrammer's way !! , thank u for your time responding my question . !!!